# how does the encoded PHP code work on Apache server?

Tags: php, encode

i have his small query.I used the website :http://www.fopo.com.ar/ to encode all of my PHP codes.I encoded all of them and replaced them with my normal codes.The codes still work in the encoded form.I was curious how this happened.Does apache server has some kind of functionality to read the encoded PHP codes?

Comment: The code is _obfuscated_. The code is still pure, plain PHP code and does not require anything special to run. Obfuscated code is just made harder to read by renaming all symbols to short random characters, removing newlines and spaces, etc.

Comment: http://www.fopo.com.ar/  uses `eval` & `base64_*`, i wont use this at all. What benefit do you have when `obfuscate` your code? It makes developing way harder? Just ensure that nobody cant read/see your code and you are fine. And finally using http://www.fopo.com.ar/ makes the performance of you page slower.

Comment: well I made a pos application for a coffee shop.the application is used offline...so I used this fopo.com.ar so after i deliver the application no noe else would be able to read my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very genuine.
It can be answered in several sections.

**What does fopo do:**
As mentioned by @JustOnUnderMillions, what `fopo` does is that it converts your code into a base 64 encoded string and then adds that code into an eval function parameter so that it gets executed.

**Does apache server has some kind of functionality to read the encoded PHP codes?**

No, as now you already know the code is plain PHP code that is base 64 encoded and passed into eval to run, it is processed in the same way a normal php file would do, apache can either use PHP as a CGI-binary or as a module either way when a request to php file is received by apache it calles the PHP hander of the sytem, which does all the PHP processing and then tells apache to return the processed response to the user.

You should read more about PHP obuscation at the below links:

https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/understanding-obfuscated-code-deobfuscate-php-javascript/

https://www.quora.com/What-is-PHP-Obfuscator-and-how-it-works